# Issue with writing values in an excel sheets with poi library for java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am getting values from my program and I want to save them in an Excel file, I am using poi library, I should have 9 sheets and in each single sheet I have to obtain a matrix (row* columns) in my case (whatever number of rows * 13 columns),,but I only obtain 1 sheet named by the last name in the array and filled only by the column number 13

Here is the method

```
public static void writeExcelSheet(String categoryName) throws IOException {
    Workbook workbook=new HSSFWorkbook();
    Sheet sheet=workbook.createSheet(categoryName);
    int allength=arraylistCategory.size();

    for(int row=0;row<allength;row++){
        for(int column=0;column<13;column++){
             Cell cell=sheet.createRow(row).createCell(column);
             cell.setCellValue(arraylistCategory.get(row)[column]);
        }
    }

        FileOutputStream outputStream=new FileOutputStream("mel coef excel sheet.xls");
        workbook.write(outputStream);
        outputStream.close();



    arraylistCategory.clear();
}
```

can you please tell me whats missing or wrong,thanks in advance

Comment: After each `Workbook workbook=new HSSFWorkbook();` `workbook` is a new empty Excel workbook without sheets. Then `Sheet sheet=workbook.createSheet(categoryName);` creates the first sheet in that workbook.

Comment: As I see, you're just creating one Sheet by the statement `Sheet sheet=workbook.createSheet(categoryName);`, I guess you should get `categoryName` from `arraylistCategory` variable instead, right?

Comment: Nguyen Phung,yes sir categoryName is an array with the names of the sheets names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I should have 9 sheets

Your method only creates one sheet in the workbook.  Assuming you are attempting to call this method 9 times, you are re-creating a new, blank `Workbook` each time you call this method, overwriting the file each time.  This explains why you are only getting the last name in the array.

Instead, create the `Workbook` once, then pass it into this method so you can create sheets on the same `Workbook`.  Then after the last call to this method, then write it to the `FileOutputStream`.

> and filled only by the column number 13

You have a similar problem here.  You are creating the row with `createRow(row)` for each column.  When you do this, you are overwriting whatever row was there with a new, empty `Row`, erasing all cell values except for the last value.  Create the `Row` outside the inner `for` loop but inside the outer `for` loop, and use it inside the inner `for` loop.

```
for(int row = 0; row < allength; row++){
    Row currentRow = sheet.createRow(row);
    for(int column = 0; column < 13; column++){
         Cell cell = currentRow.createCell(column);
         cell.setCellValue(arraylistCategory.get(row)[column]);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your explanation... I understand the process now